# Solving $\int\frac{1}{x(x⁷+1)}dx$ without using substitutions/parts

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$\int\frac{1}{x(x⁷+1)}dx$ without using substitution or by parts.
My problem is how to solve the algebra in it which methods are available to solve it? 
$1=(x^7+1)-x^7$
then we substitute in 1 and the integration became easy.
I don't know how this is possible.

Comment: Please make sure my edit is correct. You wrote $1/x(x^7+1)$ which could also mean $\frac{x^7+1}{x}$.

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How exactly do you expect to be able to evaluate this with only algebra?  Substitution and integration by parts are the *easiest* methods to evaluate antiderivatives.  Without them, all you're left with is much harder techniques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because I don't think it'll be possible to evaluate your antiderivative with any technique simpler than substitution or integration by parts, here's a hint that'll let you solve by substitution.

With partial fraction decomposition, you can show that $$\require{enclose}\enclose{box}{\frac{1}{x(x^7+1)} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x^6}{x^7+1}}$$

Comment: Actually now this  doesn't need substitutions at all. Now the antiderivative is straight forward by the fact that $\int (f'/f)=\ln f$

Comment: If you're recognizing the result of the chain rule, you're *essentially* using substitution, IMO.

Comment: 1=(x⁷+1)-x⁷ can you explain this?

Comment: @JoãoNogueira I agree that $1 = (b+1)-b$ for any $b$.  What do you mean?

Comment: I mean if we put this expression in the integral we can solve it then we only need is split it

Comment: It's basically just a slightly quicker way to get my result.  So feel free to do it that way if you prefer.

Comment: Why not go all the way with partial fractions, though?  If this question had showed up on my homework, that's what I'd expect my professor intended.

Comment: @user361424 I don't know what you mean by "go all the way with partial fractions".  But notice that the first term integrates to $\ln|x|$ and the second to $\frac 17\ln|x^7+1|$ after $u$-substitution.  So this is a particularly easy form to evaluate.

Comment: @Bye_World, I mean fully factor $x^7+1$ by noting that it's $$(x+1)((-x)^6+(-x)^5+(-x)^4+(-x)^3+(-x)^2+(-x)+1) = (x+1)[(-x)^6 = 1](x + \zeta_1)\cdots(x + \zeta_6)$$ where $\zeta_n$ marks the nonreal 7th roots of unity.  Yes, the way you describe would be easier, but if the OP was asked not to use substitution...

Comment: ...I mean, $[(-1)^6 = 1]$... obviously... not $(-x)$.